# How to check items in CheckedListBox based on DataTable value in WinForms?

Tags: c#

I fill my CheckedListBox using DataSource

```
                CheckedListBox.DataSource = this.datatable;
                CheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
                CheckedListBox.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I aim to check items based on datatable values with where clause

I'm trying to use this code

```
foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ( dr["Id"].ToString().Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<int>("State") == 1).ToString() == ((DataRowView)CheckedListBox.Items[i])[0].ToString())

                    {
                        checkboxlist.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }

                }
            }
```

But it doesn't work.

If i remove this

```
.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<int>("State") == 1).ToString()
```

The code is working but with checking all items.

So, how can i check a specific items that refer to "Id" in datatable that  equal to value of CheckedListBox and column "state" in datatable == 1?

Any help ..?

Comment: You are not checking a against the Database. You are checking against a DataTable in memory, using LINQ. There is a whole mapping layer missing. | As a general rule, String is a terrible type to use for porcessing. You got a ID. This ID should be some form of integer (unless someone messed up there). So parse the "SelectedID" back to integer and filter on that.

Comment: Can u explain more with examples please?

Comment: This code `dr["Id"].ToString().Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<bool>("State") == true).ToString()` returns `system.linq.enumerable+whereenumerableiterator 1 [system.data.data.row]` .. What should i do to return the Id?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in 2 ways

1. The long way: is to create another DataTable and insert the filtered Ids into it, then call the new DataTable in the foreach, Here is the code:

   ```
    DataTable dtId = datatable.Clone();
    var rows = datatable.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => x.Field<bool>(2) == true).ToList();

           foreach (var row in rows)
           {
               dtId.ImportRow(row);
           }

   foreach (DataRow dr in dtId.Rows)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < CheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
           {
               if ( dr["Id"].ToString() == ((DataRowView)CheckedListBox.Items[i])[0].ToString())

               {
                   CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
               }

           }
       }
   ```
2. And the simple way that i use is to change this line:

   ```
    if ( dr["Id"].ToString().Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<int>("State") == 1).ToString() == ((DataRowView)CheckedListBox.Items[i])[0].ToString())
   ```

to this:

```
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr[2].ToString()) == true && dr[0].ToString() == ((DataRowView)CheckedListBox.Items[i])[0].ToString())
```